# Using Talend Open Studio DI to extract extract value from unique 1st row before continuing to process columns

Tags: talend, data-integration

I have a number of excel files where there is a line of text (and blank row) above the header row for the table.

What would be the best way to process the file so I can extract the text from that row AND include it as a column when appending multiple files? Is it possible without having to process each file twice?

**Example**

```
This file was created on machine A on 01/02/2013

Task|Quantity|ErrorRate

0102|4550|6 per minute
0103|4004|5 per minute
```

And end up with the data from multiple similar files

```
Task|Quantity|ErrorRate|Machine|Date
0102|4550|6 per minute|machine A|01/02/2013
0103|4004|5 per minute|machine A|01/02/2013
0467|1264|2 per minute|machine D|02/02/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a small, crude sample of how it can be done.  I call it crude because a. it is not dynamic,  you can add more files to process but you need to know how many files in advance of building your job, and b. it shows the basic concept, but would require more work to suite your needs. For example, in my test files I simply have "MachineA" or "MachineB" in the first line.  You will need to parse that data out to obtain the machine name and the date.

But here is how may sample works.  Each Excel is setup as two inputs.  For the header the `tFileInput_Excel` is configured to read only the first line while the body `tFileInput_Excel` is configured to start reading at line 4.

In the `tMap` they are combined (not joined) into the output schema.  This is done for the Machine A Excel and Machine B excels, then those `tMaps` are combined with a `tUnite` for the final output.

As you can see in the log row the data is combined and includes the header info.

[image]

Comment: An elegant solution, the idea of using 2 inputs from the same file never entered my head.  Would there be any issues 1) regarding file locks blocking 1 of the inputs or  2) at tMap not having the header data processed in time for the lookup (or does talend handle that seemlessly)

Comment: As long as you are not writing to the file I believe you will be fine regarding the file lock.  My sample worked fine but only had a few rows, I suggest you try a volume test based on the number of rows you will have in production.  The big downside to this approach is that its not dynamic.  Will you have a fixed number of files coming in each time?

Comment: also, I have in the past put meta data like machine name (in your case) and date embedded in the filename.  Then you can obtain it from there and do not have to worry about reading the file with 2 inputs.